# Can I simulate the bad internet situation like limit data transfer speed

Tags: node.js, module

I use node.js to develop app, I want simulate some bad internet situation when people surfer on the internet,

like limit the data transfer speed, or delay some css or js file transfer

How can I achieve these goals?Is there some goal can do this?

Comment: What is your app? Is it a web server? Or is it a client, like a web browser?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: just a web app or website, I want test some performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) in the past to test unstable/slow internet connections on my apps. Fiddler has a modem speed option. Set that and you get incredibly slow speeds. You can also download a plugin called [Delayed Responses](http://fiddlerdelayext.codeplex.com/), it will delay the packets from arriving back at to your app.

If that isnt up your ally, then I would suggest looking for a web based proxy that will allow you to control the parameters of the requests you want. Just google it.